# how can I use GET_CONTENT for audio only?

Tags: java, android, file, audio, android-intent

After using this code:

```
    public void getContent() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GET_CONTENT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // No compatible file manager was found.
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_filemanager_installed, 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

the phone pops up a window where you can choose between audio or images file. I just want the audio and I don't want that the user can choose the image files. how can I do to not show this window and automatically go to audio selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `intent.setType("audio/*");`

Comment: and how can i directly chose the defoult android tool for audio file selection?

Comment: I don't know if there is only one same default on every device

Comment: ok... thanks however... if you'll find it you''ll get the asnwer